# How to make web service tell request that SOAP header is required?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I created a web service, written in Java and generated using Eclipse & Axis2. I created a ws-security policy in my services.xml file and created an authentication handler. I am completely new to web services, so forgive if my statements are completely wrong. After I have generated the web service and have a wsdl, I create a SOAPUi project and it generates requests. The soapui generated requests have the soap header as blank, so when I run the request I receive a security exception that authentication failed. When I enter the proper header:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-12468716">
<wsu:Created>2008-06-23T13:17:13.841Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2008-06-23T13:22:13.841Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-31571602">
<wsse:Username>alice</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">bobPW</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
<wsa:To>http://localhost:8081/axis2/services/sample01</wsa:To>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:AEDBA74A8D1FC94B631214227032877</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:Action>urn:echo</wsa:Action>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Then it works. Is there something that my wsdl is missing that tells SoapUi to automatically generate this header with question marks, ?, in the username and password fields? Because I have used SoapUi for other wsdl's where it did generate these headers automatically.

Comment: man refrain from giving original URLs this is not secure any body can acceess this http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the username and password on SOAP UI, this can be set at test request properties tab or test properties.

try this : http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/authenticating-soap-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes jon, you are correct. In your wsdl, you need to add these username and password field in request message structure as header. Also you need to implement it in your code to fetch username and password from header and execute accordingly.

Also u can specify username and password in SOAP UI, at test request properties tab. It will automatically add header in your outgoing soap request with username and password. You can also disable this functionality in preferences if you want.

Thanks,
ambuj